# Woocommerce Products by Author

Tags: wordpress, post, woocommerce, author

I am trying to list woocommerce product by author.
I followed this steps:

entered this code on `theme/functions.php`

```
add_action('init', 'wpse_74054_add_author_woocommerce', 999 );

function wpse_74054_add_author_woocommerce() {
add_post_type_support( 'product', 'author' );
}
```

This let me assigned an author to each product on the edit product tab.

I am able also able to display the product title the author and description using this code:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>

<span class="postauthortop author vcard">
<i class="icon-user"></i> <?php echo __('by', 'virtue');?> <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>" rel="author"><?php echo get_the_author() ?></a>
<div class="short_description">
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

However, when people click on author's name only regular post will be shown. Not products.

I want to creat an author page where people can see a list of product by a singular author.

I have tried creating an author.php file using the following code, but is not working.

```
<?php $author_id = the_author_meta('ID'); ?>

<?php $args = array( $author_id => 'author' , 'post_type' => 'product' ); ?>

<?php $author_posts = get_posts ( $args ); ?>

<?php while( $author_posts->have_posts() ) : $author_posts->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?
```

If anyone knows to write this code, please help me. Please, be specific as I am not familiar with coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well i did something like that on a bookstore woo site and spite that complicated thing you try to do i just use an attribute called Authors and there i have all authors names as terms of this taxonomy (authors) . So then is just to add authors to the products. Rest is quite same as looping just products for a particular author, like categories or attributes (taxonomies). You can add a woo filter nav by attributes, clicking an author will show all those products that belongs to him. In fact you can do all this thing from admin without touch any single file on theme. In my opinion of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try to specify the `post_type` to be `product` globally when on `is_author()`?

It would be something like this (add this code to your functions.php):

```
<?php

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
function my_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if ($query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'product');
    }
}

?>
```

FYI, from the code blocks that you've submitted in your question, leave the first one (as you will still need to set the author for particular products), but you probably won't be needing the second and the third code block.

**EDIT**

To display products per author in a separate URL, insert the following code into your functions.php:

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_custom_rewrite_rules');
function my_custom_rewrite_rules($rewrite) {
    $rewrite->rules = array(
        'author-products/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&post_type=product'
    ) + $rewrite->rules;
}
```

then go to `Settings -> Permalinks` and click the `Save Changes` button.

Your URLs will then be like: `http://example.com/author-products/admin/`

Comment: Hi Marin, You are my Hero!! Thank you so much! One more thing:   Is it possible to display these post_types on an alternative author page? Something like domain.com/author-products/author-name? And leave the original domain.com/author/author-name page as it was, displaying regular posts? 
 Thanks again for your generous help!

Comment: I've edited my answer above to contain an example solution for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I hope you don't mind if I ask one more thing: What should I write if I want to provide a link to the author list of products on the profile page for every author. I have this <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>" rel="author"><?php echo get_the_author() ?></a> that will link to the regular post. What will be the same but for "products"? Thanks again for all your help!!

Comment: Use: `<a href="<?php echo str_replace('/author/', '/author-products/', get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))); ?>" rel="author"><?php echo get_the_author() ?></a>`. If you find my answer helpful, don't forget to vote it up and accept the answer.

Comment: Marin, I am sorry to bother you again. Is there a way to show only the regular posts on domain/author/author-name ? This page shows the regular posts AND the products. And I already have set the domain/author-product/author-name page to only display products. Would you please provide this last help? Thanks in advanced

Comment: Try changing `$query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query()` to `$query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query() && !strstr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/author/')`. And don't forget to vote up my above answer in addition to accepting it.

Comment: Thanks a lor again! It says that I need 15 of reputation to vote up! I will give you all my votes. You saved me!